# I don't want jQuery click event of underlying div

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-events

I have some div with its click actions and another div inside first - 'close-cross' on right-top corner witch close the first one or wherever else.

Problem is that when close-cross div is clicked, the main div click action is called too. Theoretically both are clicked, because the mouse button was pressed, and mouse pointer was above both divs, but I want only the div that is clicked directly to call its click event.

Comment: Can you please post your html/javascript code?

Comment: I *think* I understand what you're asking, but putting together a fiddle or showing some markup would be more helpful in understanding what you're getting at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use the `event.stopPropagation()` method. This prevents events bubbling up the DOM tree. [See the jQuery documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 1):

In the close function you'll want to call event.stopPropagation()

http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/

This will prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent div. More on event bubbling:

[What is event bubbling and capturing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4616694/what-is-event-bubbling-and-capturing)

Answer (score 1):

Event Bubbling, is what this is called, and it can be checked using this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#main').click(function(event) {
if (event.target == this) {
//Your code here
}
});
});
```

the `event.stopPropagation();` stops journey of the event

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#close-cross').click(function(event) {

    //Your code here
   event.stopPropagation();
    });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

[Check this FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/LacBx/1/)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     // Outer Div click Event
    $('div.a').on('click', function(e) {
        if (e.target.className === 'b') {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        else {
            alert('Outer Div Clicked !!');

        }
    });

    // Inner Div Click event
    $('div.b').on('click', function(e) {
        alert('Inner Div Clicked !!');
    });
});​
```